# VB.NET- Disabling Alt + F4 From Closing My Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So, I am designing a fake virus application in `vb.net` using `winform` wherein the form's `opacity` property would be set to `45` and its `background color` would be set to `white` which would give it a frosted look so that it looks that the computer has hanged.

But, the problem is that when i press `Alt+F4`, it closes the application but i want the application to close only when `x` key is pressed and i am able to achieve this by putting this code in the form's `keydown` event.

```
          If e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
                 Application.Exit
          EndIf
```

But, I don't know how to disable `Alt+F4` From Closing My Application. Is There Any Way To achieve This? Thanks For The Help In Advance.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?351533-Disable-Close-Button-and-Prevent-Form-Being-Moved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop the app from closing, use the form closing event.  It will prevent the form from closing for any reason:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If (e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

To ext the application using the X key, use keydown event

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.X Then
        Application.Exit
      End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: but, i want to close my application when the key  x  is pressed.....and, with your code, the application is not closing even when i press x key....

Comment: but, i want to close my application when the key x is pressed.....and, with your code, the application is not closing even when i press x key..

Comment: Use keydown event to capture that, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Private keyPressAltF4 As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If keyPressAltF4 = True Then
        keyPressAltF4 = False
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    keyPressAltF4 = False
    If e.Alt = True Then
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F4 Then
            e.Handled = True
            e = Nothing
            keyPressAltF4 = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```